# Problem during accessing nested array objects in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

How can i access the array structure given below. if i am trying this `*ngFor="let item of bookedItems[0]"`  i think its allow me to access only **array[0]** data. what about **array[1], array[2]....array[n]**. how i get them?

```
  [Array(2)]
      0: Array(2)
        0: {id: 2, name: "Calark", price: 375, …}
        1: {id: 5, name: "Eternis", price: 450, …}
        length: 2
      __proto__: Array(0)
      length: 1
      __proto__: Array(0)
```

**inside component**

```
export class BookingComponent implements OnInit {
  bookedItems = [];
  constructor(private bookingService:BookingService) { }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.bookedData();
    console.log(this.bookedItems);
  }

  bookedData(){
    this.bookedItems = this.bookingService.getBookedItem();
  }
}
```

**inside template**

```
<h3>Your Bookings:</h3>
<div *ngIf="bookedItems.length > 0; else plainText">
  <div class="cart-item" *ngFor="let item of bookedItems[0]">
<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
          <div class="flip-card-front">
            <img [src]="item.imagePath" alt="{{item.name}}" class="img-responsive" style="max-height: 305px" width="293px">
          </div>


          <div class="flip-card-back">
            <small>
                  <p>Name: {{item.name}}</p>
                  <p>Size: {{item.size}}</p>
                  <p>Price: {{item.price}}</p>
                  <p>City: {{item.city}}</p>
                  <p>Address: {{item.address}}</p>
            </small>
          </div>

     </div>
     </div><hr/>
  </div>
</div>


<ng-template #plainText>
  <p>You haven't booked any item. please book to get your booking details!!!</p>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: can you please post a bit more of what you've tried so far

Comment: @digital-pollution sure u can check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll definetly need a double loop here, unless the fact you have a nested array is a bug. In case it's not, you should probably use "ng-container" directive like this =>

```
<h3>Your Bookings:</h3>
<div *ngIf="bookedItems.length > 0; else plainText">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let bookedItem of bookedItems">
    <div class="cart-item" *ngFor="let item of bookedItem">
      <div class="flip-card">
        <div class="flip-card-inner">
          <div class="flip-card-front">
            <img [src]="item.imagePath" alt="{{item.name}}" class="img-responsive" style="max-height: 305px"
                 width="293px">
          </div>
          <div class="flip-card-back">
            <small>
              <p>Name: {{item.name}}</p>
              <p>Size: {{item.size}}</p>
              <p>Price: {{item.price}}</p>
              <p>City: {{item.city}}</p>
              <p>Address: {{item.address}}</p>
            </small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr/>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>


<ng-template #plainText>
  <p>You haven't booked any item. please book to get your booking details!!!</p>
</ng-template>
```

I hope it helped you a bit.

Comment: what's the role of <ng-container> here?

Comment: Sometimes you don't wanna create a useless div or whatever html block just to be able to iterate over arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I didnt realize, that the array is nested. You could try a double loop:

```
  <div class="cart-item" *ngFor="let item of bookedItems">
    <div class="flip-card" *ngFor="let innerItem of item">
      <div class="flip-card-inner">
        <div class="flip-card-front">
          <img [src]="innerItem.imagePath" alt="{{innerItem.name}}" class="img-responsive" style="max-height: 305px" width="293px">
        </div>


        <div class="flip-card-back">
          <small>
              <p>Name: {{innerItem.name}}</p>
              <p>Size: {{innerItem.size}}</p>
              <p>Price: {{innerItem.price}}</p>
              <p>City: {{innerItem.city}}</p>
              <p>Address: {{innerItem.address}}</p>
          </small>
        </div>

     </div>
    </div><hr/>
 </div>
```

If I'd face this issue, I would flatten the arrays first, given that there's only one level of nesting.

Comment: If i am doing this `*ngFor="let item of bookedItems"` i am not able to access `{{item.name}} {{item.price}}....` and so on..